# C++,ラムダ式を用いたメンバ関数のバインド方法に関して

Tags: c++

関数の引数としてメンバ関数とオブジェクトを取り，std::bindでのメンバ関数のキャプチャ
`std::function<void()> Func = std::bind(&Foo::FooFunc, &foo);`
と同じように，
`std::function<void()> Func = [&Foo::FooFuncに相当するもの, foo](){FooFuncを呼び出す処理}`
とすることは可能でしょうか．
また，可能な場合，どのようなコードになりますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
std::function<void()> Func = [&foo]{ foo->Foo::FooFunc(); };
```

とか、クラス名を明示する必要なければ省略して

```
std::function<void()> Func = [&foo]{ foo->FooFunc(); };
```

とか書けます。